# Getting wrong json format printing on console in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, express, dart, dio

I tried to parse the json data in flutter but it seems that json data is not in the correct format, when I checked in the browser the json data is in the correct format. Below I attaching both screenshots.
and I made my own local server using express, I think it doesn't need here since I am getting good responses in the browser. If needed I can share or update here.
[image: Browser screenshot]

[image: Android Studio flutter response]

Can anyone explain what went wrong here, I was unable to parse data with the response that I got in the flutter console.

I am using below code to convert

```
import 'dart:convert';

Tasks tasksFromJson(String str) => Tasks.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String tasksToJson(Tasks data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Tasks {
  Tasks({
    required this.tasks,
  });

  List<Task> tasks;

  factory Tasks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Tasks(
    tasks: List<Task>.from(json["tasks"].map((x) => Task.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "tasks": List<dynamic>.from(tasks.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Task {
  Task({
    required this.completed,
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.v,
  });

  bool completed;
  String id;
  String name;
  int v;

  factory Task.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Task(
    completed: json["completed"],
    id: json["_id"],
    name: json["name"],
    v: json["__v"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "completed": completed,
    "_id": id,
    "name": name,
    "__v": v,
  };
}
```

then

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:task_manager/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:task_manager/models/tasks_model.dart';

class DioClient {
  final Dio dio = Dio();

  Future fetchTasks() async {
    try{
      final response = await dio.get(baseURL+"/tasks");
      final tasks = tasksFromJson(response.data);
      debugPrint("${response.data}");
    } on DioError catch(e){
      debugPrint("StatusCode: ${e.toString()}");
      throw Exception("Failed to load Tasks");
    }
  }
}
```

and errors are

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type '_JsonMap'
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49      throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 99:3        castError
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 485:10  cast
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 719:17                as
packages/task_manager/services/dio_client.dart 12:21                                                                           fetchTasks
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1660:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 558:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 47:12                                         complete
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future.dart 613:44                                             onValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1660:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 567:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 640:7                                         callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15               <fn>
```

Update!!
After all, I got to know Dio encodes the JSON response from REST API as a response

[image]

We can stop this to get plain data in Dio options

```
options: Options( 
    responseType: ResponseType.plain,
  )
```

or below accepted answer also will work.

Comment: Can you show directly what error did you got by parsing the JSON ? Also include the code you use for the parsing.

Comment: I updated my code and errors can you look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that response.data is already a JsonMap.

Try to change this:

```
final tasks = tasksFromJson(response.data);
```

with this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
// ...
final tasks = tasksFromJson(jsonEncode(response.data));
```

UPDATE:

A better solution would be this one:

```
Tasks.fromJson(Map.from(response.data));
```

Comment: yeah Its working, so dio converting response to JsonMap. am I right?

Comment: yes, you can find further information on how Dio uses conversions in the official documentation. P.S. It would be great if you can accept my answer, thanks :)